# How to get all file names in current directory?

Tags: c++, file, rename

My goal is to build a program that renames all files in the current working directory so they don't have any spaces, any special characters or any accented characters (for example  É would become E). I'm planning on using `int rename(const char *oldname, const char *newname);` . My problem is how do I get the files in the current working directory? I would like to have the executable I'm creating put in a folder with a files with bad names and run it and the files all be renamed.

A platform independent solution would be preferable, otherwise I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise 32bit.

This question isn't a duplicate because I don't know the path for `opendir ("c:\\src\\");` it's whatever directory the program is being executed from.

Comment: `boost::filesystem` has a `directory_iterator` or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: I was confused because I thought I had to use the Boost library but I red in this question it had been deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108650/replacement-for-deprecated-boost-filesystem-initial-path So no need for boost?

Comment: @Celeritas Boost.Filesystem hasn't been deprecated. The question is about one particular function that has been deprecated. Use Boost.Filesystem, it's far easier to use than the other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code to do that:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/869208-list-files-directory

In essence you utilize these APIs: `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`

For cross-platform solution see `findfirst()` and `findnext()`

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use opendir(".") , this will open the current directory.

Comment: It looks that the current C++ standard has no convenient interface for reading all files in a directory.  Future version should add this functionality.  The unix system has all the C interfaces for dealing with filesystems.  Unix actually is very good at this with the abstraction of File to represent all filesystem objects.